# How to write integration tests for Rest Service API in spock

Tags: java, rest, spock

I have a Java class which contains API method

Ex:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Resposce getIds(@PathParam(name) String name) {
     //some code here 
}
```

I want to right integration test for this API i.e while testing I want to call this method using `path` but not using method name

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible test case ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get help on StackOverflow. At least show a full Spock test and source code of all classes involved in that test, please. P.S.: You are really flooding SO with your unqualified questions. No offense meant, I want to help you and am sure other people do, too. But according to the "garbage in, garbage out" principle you won't get any good answers for badly written questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
import com.charter.aesd.testcommons.RESTSpecification
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator


class TestIT extends RESTSpecification{

    def BASE_URL = "/test"
    def "Get test"(){
        when:
        HttpResponseDecorator response = getRestClient().get([path:"$BASE_URL"+"/123"])

        then:
            response.status >=200 && response.status < 400
    }

    @Override
    String getBaseUrl() {
        return 'http://localhost:8889/'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Spring guides on their site:
[Testing Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Comment: Welcome here, Jonasz. Please be advised that answers mainly consisting of links are not considered okay here on SO. A good answer should really solve the original poster's problem and explain how and why. Links are fine, but only for further information.

Answer (score 0):

As you are explicitly asking for Spock: here is my standard implementation for an `ApiSpec`:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
abstract class AbstractServiceSpec extends Specification {

    protected final static RestTestClient api = new RestTestClient()

    @Value('http://localhost:${local.server.port}')
    String serviceUrl

    def setup() {
        api.baseUrl = serviceUrl
    }

    def "GET /health should return 200"() {
        expect:
        api.get("/health").code() == 200
    }
}
```

Note that `RestTestClient` is my own wrapper around OkHttp. You can use any HTTP client at hand of course.

The `@SpringBootTest` annotation makes Spring starting up the whole service. At the time your test gets executed, there service is fully up and running and you can black-box-test your API.

Generally [Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) is a good read and most of it –as you can see in the example– can done in Spock as well as in JUnit.